# Return SQL results in one row

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to populate a table in HTML using a PHP script, which runs an SQL query which returns the following results (example):

```
 UserID  |  Name  |  Month  | Value  |
   1     |  Joe   |   Jan   | 123.00 |
   1     |  Joe   |   Feb   | 22.00  |
   1     |  Joe   |  March  | 32.50  |
  21     |  Derek |   Jan   | 45.76  |
  21     |  Derek |  March  | 12.31  |
```

But when I want to populate the table in PHP I want the table to look like this:

```
 Name   |   January  |  February  |  March  |
  Joe   |    123.00  |   22.00    |  32.50  |
 Derek  |    45.76   |            |  12.31  |
```

But when generating the table using a PHP while loop its doing the following, which I would expect, as it's just looping through each fetched row:

```
 Name   |   January  |  February  |  March  |
  Joe   |    123.00  |            |         |
  Joe   |    22.00   |            |         |
  Joe   |    32.500  |            |         |
 Derek  |    45.76   |            |         | ... etc`
```

As I said, I would expect it to behave this way, but is there anyway to get it to display in the 2nd example.

I've already worked out some logic to place the values in the correct location, but it's still on a separate row, so at the moment it looks like this, which isn't ideal.

```
 Name   |   January  |  February  |  March  |
  Joe   |    123.00  |            |         |
  Joe   |            |    22.00   |         |
  Joe   |            |            |  32.50  |
 Derek  |    45.76   |            |         |
```

I hope I'm not missing anything obvious but I've had a look at several solutions within SQL but just can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDITED:**

Apologies, my SQL query is taking data from two different tables, as I am comparing values, so my understanding was that I couldn't use the GROUP BY statement. Here is my SQL query:

`SELECT dbo_tstUser.UserID, dbo_tstUser.Name, dbo_tstUser.Month, dbo_tstUser.Value, dbo_tstUserImport.Value FROM dbo_tstUser INNER JOIN dbo_tstUserImport ON dbo_tstUser.UserID = dbo_tstUserImport.UserID;`

Comment: Your version of the query is missing a `group by`.  You should really include it in the question.

Comment: there's no "php" here, so that may depend on how you're trying to query this through some form of loop. There's also no query posted.

Comment: you have answers below; see those. If they didn't solve this, you'll know why. As per my above comment and Gordon's.

Comment: Please read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and expand your question with the code you used to create your (wrong) output. Right now you are asking us to fully implement your solution from scratch which is not what this site is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation to do the pivoting:

```
select UserId, name, 
    max(case when Month = 'Jan' then value end) as January,
    max(case when Month = 'Feb' then value end) as February,
    max(case when Month = 'March' then value end) as March
from your_table
group by UserId, name;
```

If you don't want the UserId in the result, you can use:

```
select name, 
    max(case when Month = 'Jan' then value end) as January,
    max(case when Month = 'Feb' then value end) as February,
    max(case when Month = 'March' then value end) as March
from your_table
group by UserId, name;
```

Note that I kept the UserId in the group by clause to keep different people with same name separate.

Comment: Thank you GurV, this might work, but I'm selecting from two different tables, so I don't think I'd be able to use the GROUP BY statement, but I might be able to use this solution to do another comparison table. Thank you.

Comment: @CalBrown - Why can't you use group when selecting from two different tables? (possibly ask another question providing what the tables hold and what you want from them). This answer answers your intially asked question

Comment: Yes, I agree GurV, I'll look into the GROUPing of multiple tables, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a GROUP BY name statement to your SQL:-

```
SELECT UserID, Name, Month, Value
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

Edit:-

```
SELECT dbo_tstUser.UserID, dbo_tstUser.Name, dbo_tstUser.Month, dbo_tstUser.Value, dbo_tstUserImport.Value 
FROM dbo_tstUser 
INNER JOIN dbo_tstUserImport ON dbo_tstUser.UserID = dbo_tstUserImport.UserID
GROUP BY dbo_tstUser.UserID;
```